# Как сделать умный поиск по списку

Tags: c#

Есть класс `DB`

```
class DB
    {
        public string Tovar { get; set; }
        public string Mnn { get; set; }
    }
```

Стоит задача составить умный поиск по `List<DB>`. Думал использовать расстояние Левенштейна. Но чем оно не нравится. Если исходное слово `приветмосквасегоднявсехорошо` и если сравнивать его со словом "все" мы получаем расстояние Левенштейна очень большое. Как объединить расстояние Левенштейна и Сontains? Я бы мог использовать просто Contains, но может быть так что искомое слово может быть ,например, всея.

Comment: `if (mystring.Contains(filter) || levenstein(mystring, filter)) { ... }` ?

Comment: `Стоит задача составить умный поиск` вы не расписали что это означает. Я, например, не знаю, что вы имееет ввиду.

Comment: @tym32167 я хочу найти  "похожие" слова. Contains similar

Comment: критерий похожести слова какой? Как понять, похож ли Петя на Васю?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, допустим есть 10 слов в списке :приветземлясвамия1,приветземлясвамия2,приветземлясвамия3,..  Я хочу проверить есть ли совпадения слова "зимля". По идее отличается только один символ, но я хочу чтобы он находил такие совпадения

Comment: тогда расстояние левенштейна вам не поможет, оно не учитывает, что буквы рядом должны стоять

Comment: @tym32167: на самом деле его очень легко под это модифицировать. Вообще очень красивый алгоритм: если слишком легко расширить под свои нужды

Comment: @Kir_Antipov хотел бы я глянуть на такую модификацию :) она, скорее всего, превратится во что то, похожее на мой ответ

Comment: Могу вечерком откопать пример (я недавно реализовывал по свои нужды) и скинуть в запрещённом на территории ruSO чатике :D Только пинганите меня, если будет интересно, а то я забуду)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ну если только сам не забуду. Да и зачем туда скидывать, пишите ответ здесь :)

Comment: @tym32167: а я больше не отвечаю хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov понял )

Comment: @Kir_Antipov скиньте плиз

Comment: @Kir_Antipov думаю конкурс смотивирует вас

Comment: @Radzhab: SOпротивление не продаётся!

Comment: )) @Kir_Antipov

Answer (score 3):

Быстрый пример, хочу показать только идею. Код можно ускорить и я не смотрел крайние случае вообще

```
private bool SmartContains(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.Length < s2.Length) return SmartContains(s2, s1);

    for(int i=0; i<=(s1.Length - s2.Length); i++)
    {
        int difs = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<s2.Length; j++)
        {
            if (s1[i+j] != s2[j]) difs++;
            if (difs > 1) break;
        }       
        if (difs<=1) return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Код работает за квадратичное время, но его, по идее, можно ускорить. 
Пример использования

```
Console.WriteLine(SmartContains("приветземлясвамия1", "зимля"));
Console.WriteLine(SmartContains("приветземлясвамия1", "зимляz"));
Console.WriteLine(SmartContains("зимляz", "зимляz"));
```

Вывод

```
True
False
True
```